# Mysql: Select most recent entry by user and case number

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table whose data looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `cm_case_notes` (`id`, `case_id`, `date`, `time`, `description`, `username`,       `supervisor`, `datestamp`) VALUES
(45977, '1175', '2010-11-19 16:27:15', 600, 'Motion hearing...Denied.', 'bjones', 'jharvey,', '2010-11-19 21:27:15'),
(46860, '1175', '2010-12-11 16:11:19', 300, 'Semester Break Report', 'bjones', 'jharvey,', '2010-12-11 21:11:19'),
(48034, '1175', '2011-05-04 17:30:03', 300, 'test', 'bjones', 'jharvey,', '2011-05-04 22:30:03'),
(14201, '1175', '2009-02-06 00:00:00', 3600, 'In court to talk to prosecutor, re: the file', 'csmith', 'sandrews', '2009-02-07 14:33:34'),
(14484, '1175', '2009-02-13 00:00:00', 6300, 'Read transcript, note taking', 'csmith', 'sandrews', '2009-02-16 17:22:36');
```

I'm trying to select the most recent case note (by `date`) on each case by each user.  The best I've come up with is:

```
SELECT * , MAX(  `date` ) FROM cm_case_notes WHERE case_id =  '1175' GROUP BY username
```

This, however, doesn't give the most recent entry, but the first one for each user.  I've seen several similar posts here, but I just can't seem to get my brain around them.  Would anybody take pity on the sql-deficient and help?

Comment: Grouping by user name will give you the most recent for each user.  in this case, each user who responded to case_id = 1175.  You obviously will have many cases.  Is what you really want is... for each case ID, you want the most recent case comment? and then maybe group them by date? or... all cases that had activity on a given date (or range), the most recent case note for cases associated with that range?  Your question is not explicit enough.

Comment: Try the links on the right (under **Related**)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want only the dates of the most recent case note for every user and every case, you can use this:

```
--- Q ---
SELECT case_id
     , username 
     , MAX(  `date` ) AS recent_date 
FROM cm_case_notes 
GROUP BY case_id
       , username
```

If you want all the columns from these row (with most recent date) follow the Quassnoi link for various solutions (or the other provided links). The easiest to write would be to make the above query into a subquery and join it to `cm_case_notes`:

```
SELECT cn.*
FROM 
      cm_case_notes AS cn
  JOIN 
      ( Q ) AS q
    ON  ( q.case_id,  q.username,  q.recent_date ) 
      = ( cn.case_id, cn.username, cn.`date` )
```

---

If you just want the lastet case note but only for a particular `case_id`, then you could add the where condition in both `cn` and `Q` (Q slightly modified):

```
SELECT cn.*
FROM 
      cm_case_notes AS cn
  JOIN 
      ( SELECT username 
             , MAX(  `date` ) AS recent_date 
        FROM cm_case_notes 
        WHERE case_id = @particular_case_id
        GROUP BY username 
      ) AS q
    ON  ( q.username,  q.recent_date ) 
      = ( cn.username, cn.`date` )
WHERE cn.case_id = @particular_case_id
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I want to query by case (all of the columns for the most recent entry where case_id equals the target case number).  Where would I put the where clause?

Comment: If you just want the lastet case note for a particular `case_id`, then you could add teh where in both `cn` and `Q`.

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors when I run this.  Just to be clear:  In the last example, I should put the sql in the first example in for Q and replace @particular_case_id with the case number, right? SELECT cn.*
FROM 
      cm_case_notes AS cn
  JOIN 
      ( SELECT case_id
     , username 
     , MAX(  `date` ) AS recent_date 
FROM cm_case_notes 
GROUP BY case_id
       , username 
        WHERE case_id = '1175'
        GROUP BY username 
      ) AS q
    ON  ( q.username,  q.recent_date ) 
      = ( cn.username, cn.`date` )
WHERE cn.case_id = '1175'

Comment: @Judson: You are almost there. In the Q subquery, you can have only one `GROUP BY`. Remove the `GROUP BY case_id , username`

Answer (score 2):

the reason why you don't get what would like to fetch from the database is the use of `SELECT *` together with `GROUP`.

In fact, only the results of aggregate functions and / or the group field(s) itself can be safely SELECTed. selecting anything else leads to unexpected results. (the exact result depends on order, query optimization and such).

What you are trying to achieve is called fetching a "groupwise maximum". This is a common problem / common task in SQL, you can read a nice writeup here:
http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/groupwise-max/

or in the MySQL manual here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

or a detailed long explanation by stackoverflow user Quassnoi here:
http://explainextended.com/2009/11/24/mysql-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum-on-a-unique-column/

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a DESC ordering and simply limiting 1?

Comment: That won't work, I'm afraid.  I want the returned to have the most recent entry for each user on a case.